# How to code a proper checkbox that saves changes after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, code-formatting

I’m trying to do a simple personal website with checkboxes implemented into it, I’ve never done anything to do with coding ever so I’m super confused on how to put it all together. So far I have a checkbox labeled as purchased, but after I check the box and refresh the page it’s like I never checked the box. I was reading that I need local storage implemented into the code for my changes to save even after refreshing the page. But I have no idea how it should be done and what exactly I need to type in, if anyone could leave what it’s supposed to look like that would be great, thank you genuinely! What I have so far:

```
<label class="form-control">
  <input type="checkbox" name="purchased" />
  Purchased
</label>
```

Comment: That is how forms work. If you want state to be memorized that either requires severside code or JavaScript with localstorage. Plenty of "TODO list" tutorials out there.

Comment: `localStorage` will need to be used via javascript. If you aren't familiar with javascript then you'll need to learn how to add a script file to your page. Here's a link to `localStorage` and it has code examples: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Also, since this has to do with a form, I'd suggest `sessionStorage` as apposed to `localStorage` as you wouldn't want this value to pre-populate on the next visit. More about `sessionStorage`: [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Answer (score 0):

"... but after I check the box and refresh the page it’s like I never checked the box..."

Hi, according comments is necessary to save into some type storage.

Look like this:

```js
let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box').length;

function save() {   
  for(let i = 1; i <= boxes; i++){
      var checkbox = document.getElementById(String(i));
    localStorage.setItem("checkbox" + String(i), checkbox.checked); 
  }
}

//for loading
for(let i = 1; i <= boxes; i++){
  if(localStorage.length > 0){
    var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkbox" + String(i)));
    document.getElementById(String(i)).checked = checked;
  }
}
window.addEventListener('change', save);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="1" class="box">checkbox1</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" class="box">checkbox2</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="3" class="box">checkbox3</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="4" class="box">checkbox4</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="5" class="box">checkbox5</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="6" class="box">checkbox6</input><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a persistent checkbox using local storage like this:

```js
const cb = document.getElementById('checkbox');


//run every time the checkbox is set
cb.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  console.log('changed');
  localStorage.setItem('purchased', e.target.checked);
});


//run once on page load, check if it is set in LS if yes then check it
const localPurchasedValue = localStorage.getItem('purchased');
if (localPurchasedValue === 'true') {
  cb.checked = true;
}
```

```html
<label class="form-control">
  <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="purchased" />
  Purchased
</label>
```

Note this little preview will not work due to iframe restrictions on this site, but if you copy this into your own file and run with a dev server or some kind you can see it working.